# How to fill area below arbitrary curves with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing two very simple curves with `TikZ`. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\normalsize]

\draw [very thick,-Triangle] (-0.02,0) -- (10,0);   % X-axis
\draw [very thick,-Triangle] (0,0) -- (0,5);        % Y-axis

\draw [very thick] (0,0) to[out=25,in=-230] (2,3) to[out=-50,in=180] (4,0);
\draw [very thick] (2,0) to[out=0,in=-180] (4,1.5) to[out=0,in=90] (5,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result: [image]

What's the simplest way to fill in the area below the curves as shown in my mockup?

[image]

Comment: Browsing through the other answers really didn't help much (and I did search before asking), but I'll just try again. Thanks, I guess?

Comment: With those curves, the only one that needs anything extra is the purple region.  I would fill the left-hand curve fully in blue, the right-hand fully in red, and then use clipping to fill the central region in purple: `\begin{scope} \clip <left-hand page>; \fill[purple] <right-hand path>; \end{scope}`.  Also, remember to do all of the filling before drawing.